# Error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string: varchar(8000)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of type `varchar(8000)`. We save all kinds of data in it like number, text, date etc.

I wrote a simple select query to get all "Date" values from the table all works, I can also use `CAST` or `Convert` to get my value in this format `2014-12-16 00:00:00.000`.

Now I'm trying to add a `where` clause to filter this year's info, but I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

When I use TOP 10000 in my select query the error goes away. This is really strange

```
; WITH TempTable AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ID, CAST(Value AS DateTime) [SomeDate]
    FROM 
        SampleTable
    WHERE
        ColType = 'Date'
)
SELECT * 
FROM FROM TempTable 
WHERE [SomeDate] BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '12/30/2017'
```

This throws

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
; WITH TempTable AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 100000 
        ID, CAST(Value AS DateTime) [SomeDate]
    FROM 
        SampleTable
    WHERE
        ColType = 'Date'
)
SELECT * 
FROM FROM TempTable 
WHERE [SomeDate] BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '12/30/2017'
```

This works fine. Please note I have only 25 some rows in my result. Top 100000 is just a big number I used. This is very strange how my TOP keyword is making my query good.

**Update:**

Here is how I ended up resolving without using TOP keyword. I have split my query little bit as seen below. Thank you all for your time and comments.

```
;WITH GetAllIDs
AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM SampleTable
    WHERE ColType = 'Date'
    )
    ,FinalTable
AS (
    SELECT ID
        ,(
            SELECT Cast([Value] AS DATETIME)
            FROM SampleTable dt
            WHERE dt.ID = tt.ID
                AND dd.ColType = 'Date'
            ) [SomeDate]
    FROM GetAllIDs tt
    )
SELECT *FROM FinalTable
WHERE [SomeDate] BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '12/30/2017'
```

Comment: I changed the tag to "sql-server".  You might also mention which version you are using.

Answer (score 4):

There is no order of execution in a SQL statement.  So, the `where` clause does (necessarily) filter the rows before the values are converted.  Hence, your problem.

In SQL Server 2012+, there is a simple solution using `try_convert()`:

```
With TempTable AS (
      select ID, try_convert(datetime, Value) as SomeDate
      from SampleTable
      where ColType = 'Date'
     )
Select * 
from TempTable 
Where SomeDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-30';
```

Microsoft considers this behavior a *feature* of the optimizer, not a bug (I disagree).  It provides more opportunities for optimizing the query.  In this case, simple conversions are done when the data is being read, rather than further down the processing pipeline.

Notice that I also changed the date constants to YYYY-MM-DD format.  You should always use YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD for the format.

The fact that this goes away when `TOP` is added is some strange artifact of the execution plan.  For some reason, that would do the filtering *before* evaluating the expression.  I know that `TOP` can have sometimes have this effect.  I'm surprised in this case because the query is simple.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `case`.  Something like this:

```
With TempTable AS (
      select ID, (case when isdate(value) = 1 then convert(datetime, Value) end) as SomeDate
      from SampleTable
      where ColType = 'Date'
     )
Select * 
from TempTable 
Where SomeDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-30';
```

The `case` expression guarantees the order of evaluation of the arguments.  The `when` is evaluated only after the `then`.

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thanks for your comments. This problem is seen in SQL Server 2008. Is there an alternative for that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on SQL 2008, you would have to change your pattern.

First, why it works with the TOP command. TOP selects all records matching the WHERE clause in the query up to the limit of the TOP. Since you have a WHERE clause, the version with the TOP only passes records with the Coltype of 'Date' on to the date check. Without the top, the optimizer thinks that checking the value of the Value column against the date range will be faster than filtering the column type, since only one data element retrieval is required to check that, "speeding up" (in this case, blowing up) the query.

One option that should work would be to change the TempTable definition code to this:

```
; WITH TempTable AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        ID, CAST(Value AS DateTime) [SomeDate]
    FROM 
        SampleTable
    WHERE
        ColType = 'Date'
)
```

Your other obvious option would be to extract all of the values to an actual temp table, rather than using a CTE directly, then query that table.

Comment: Hi there there are too many temp tables I need to create so  Creating Droping actual Temp Tables will be overkill for what I'm doing, so I'm using CTEs.  TOP 100 PERCENT still threw "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." but TOP 99 PERCENT worked without errors but the the result skipped couple of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my update: This is how I ended up fixing my problem. Thank You Gordon, Laughing Vergil for your comments.